# Bill button is not working when reprint receipt button is true in pos in odoo11

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-11, pos

```
        I am using odoo11. In pos module when I open the session, I can click `reprint receipt`, `bill`, `split` etc. buttons. 

        When I click the `bill` button it is not showing the preview window if `reprint receipt` (backed name `iface_print_via_proxy` is true) is true.

        If I make this `iface_print_via_proxy` boolean field false it will show the bill preview.

        I checked in runbot also... The same thing happened in the runbot.

        Please, anyone help me rectify this issue...
```

Below code in pos_restaurant/static/src/js/printbill.js,
after bill button clicks this function is calling.

```
        ---->>> in printbill.js
```

Below code in pos_restaurant/static/src/js/printbill.js,
after bill button clicks this function is calling.

```
        button_click: function(){
                console.log('iface....',this.pos.config.iface_print_via_proxy)
                if (!this.pos.config.iface_print_via_proxy) {
                    this.gui.show_screen('bill');
                } else {
                    this.print_xml();
                }
            },

        Normally this code is using 
        if iface_print_via_proxy i true. then bill button calls the  this.print_xml() method. 

        put in this method 

        this.pos.proxy.print_receipt(QWeb.render('BillReceipt',{
    receipt: receipt, widget: this, pos: this.pos, order: order
        }));

        pos.proxy.print_receipt is using this is not working.

        when i change to this.pos.proxy.print_receipt(QWeb.render....
        to $(".").html(Qweb.render...

        then bill will be printed in html page..

        in runbot also same thing happens 

        please check this link
        http://364855-11-0-65ef27.runbot13.odoo.com/pos/web/?debug=1#action=pos.ui

        in this link both Bill and reprint button visible. u will only see the reprint page. not the bill page. if u want see the bill page reprint button will false then it works...

        please i thing u understand my problem.. please help..

        in v10 reprint is not working.. in v11 bill is not working at a time process..
```

Comment: It is working in runbot. Can you describe the exact issue and show the error.

Comment: Thank u for your reply, ok i will show u screenshots

Comment: Sir had edited the question, and add the link please check once please....

Comment: So you want receipt reprint preview as well as bill preview but as per you only one is working at a time right ?  The link you given is showing 404 error.

Comment: Yes sir. At a time these two buttons are not working. Link is --> open the runbot.com in that chose enterprise version, in that v11 , then open the pointof sale, and check the reprint receipt  and bill preview two are click or not, click the two buttons, and open the session and check any product sir. Please please check once u also face the same problem and tell me the result sir

Answer (score 0):

In v11 only following options are available :  [image]

From this there is not any option as per you are talking about.

Comment: Sir In Configartion>>Point of sale >>PosBox / Hardware Proxy >> click the PosBox>>then visible >>Click the Receipt Printer>>then down the page>>>Bills & Receipts >>Click the Reprint Receipt (Allow cashier to reprint receipts)

Comment: then u see the two buttons visible in pos main session page sir... please check once sir..  :)

Comment: Ahh yeah that is not working but probably if you configure remote printer attachment then why you need another print option ?

Comment: yes sir, but its a odoo standard problem, may it will correct the issue from odoo. and we will not also wait for odoo12 version sir. its way i put my question sir

Comment: Thank u for your response and check the problem sir.. :)